# Bigquery to Bigtable data transfer using google dataflow in python

Tags: python, google-bigquery, google-cloud-dataflow, dataflow, bigtable

We are using the dataflow pipeline written in JAVA for transfering data from bigquery to bigtable. 
e.g. https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-bigtable-examples/blob/master/java/dataflow-connector-examples/src/main/java/com/google/cloud/bigtable/dataflow/example/BigQueryBigtableTransfer.java

I am trying to write same code in python. But I am not able to get the bigtable dataflow connector for python. Any clue how it can be done?

Comment: The Python SDK doesn't have support for Bigtable yet. https://beam.apache.org/documentation/io/built-in/

Comment: @GrahamPolley Thanks. Do you have any idea when google guys are planning to introduce it?

Comment: The Cloud Bigtable client is actively being changed to be able to support Beam.  For now, we'll see if we ought to create a sample of how you can do the Bigtable side of things.

Comment: There is BigTable Python/batch Connector available, only for write. https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/master/sdks/python/apache_beam/io/gcp/bigtableio.py

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just not to leave the question unanswered, as Graham Polley commented: ["The Python SDK doesn't have support for Bigtable yet."](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/io/built-in/). I see that engineer from Bigtable is already involved, but if you want, you can also create a feature request in [Public Issue Tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new).

Comment: Since there's no connector yet, you can call the client library [https://cloud.google.com/bigtable/docs/samples-python-hello] within your own DoFn